# How should a bash script determine a classpath for a maven project and its dependencies?

Tags: bash, maven, classpath

Yay, my thesis is done!  Now that the pressure is off and I've had my fill of playing Skyrim, I'm converting the code I wrote for my thesis from a chaotic directory built with ant to a nice maven project.

I originally had a `bin` directory with about 20 bash scripts that ran the various java and ruby programs used in my thesis, including the final jruby/sinatra-based web server.  I am planning on moving my scripts to `src/main/scripts`, but I need to figure out how to handle the classpath.

I had previously just hardcoded paths in my scripts to the manually-downloaded dependencies.  However, now that maven is downloading and storing all the jars I need, what's the best way to reference them from my scripts:

- Should I just get the scripts to reference the full paths of various jars in the local repository like before?
- Should I make the local repository directory a configuration option for my scripts and use relative paths to this directory?
- Should I build a big hairy jar with all the dependencies using the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) and access this via the script-relative path `../../../target/*-jar-with-dependencies.jar`?
- Is there some better option I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 2):

In your script, use the `exec:java` plugin to run Java classes. It will sort out the classpath based on the defined dependencies. Then you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Relook at all the scripts that you have.   Potentially you could achieve the functionality of some of them using [maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Besides assembly and shade plugins, you may want to look at the functionalities provided by [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) as well.

Comment: -1. Maven exec plugin requires Maven to run. If the project is to be deployed and easily run, it should not have Maven as a requirement (hence the need to generate shell scripts).

Answer (score 1):

In my project (**[Soluvas fb-tools/fbcli](https://github.com/soluvas/fb-tools)**), because I use Java 6 and later (which supports [wildcard classpaths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)), here's what I do:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                
# Must run first: mvn package dependency:copy-dependencies                                 
java -cp 'target/dependency/*:target/fbcli-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain "$@"
```

No need for manual generation of classpaths. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some plugin doing similar things you mentioned. Assembly plugin you mentioned is doubtless one of them (and the way you suggested is also a neat working solution).

You may want to take a look in [AppAssembler](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) and [Shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).  They all provide some mechanism to bundle the dependencies and produce a directly executable package.

Comment: There are multiple options with the assembly plugin: The large executable jar works well, but if you have multiple Java programs to run that share a common classpath, it is not very efficient space-wise.  In such a case you might prefer to create a zip containing a lib dir with jar files and a bin dir with .sh files.

Comment: App assembler I mentioned in fact solve the problem of creating the .sh or .bat

Answer (score 0):

Here is CLI example using Maven plugin `exec:java` as mentionned by @artbristol in another comment:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="mypackage.MyClassWithMain" -Dexec.args="arg1 arg2"
```